# Use Selenium with Chromium Browser

Tags: selenium, compatibility, chromium, web-testing

In the Selenium options (on Firefox) I can find **`Custom browser`**.

Is it possible to use this option to run a Selenium test in *Chromium Browser* (not Chrome)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. For Chromium, use:

```
DefaultSelenium selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*custom path/to/chromium", "www.google.com");
selenium.start();
```

The other options that you can use are *custom, *chrome (note: this is not Google Chrome; it’s a Firefox mode only), *googlechrome, *iexplore. Please check the Selenium documentation for complete list of the modes.

Answer (score 33):

<strike>Uh, the accepted answer doesn't answer the question.  Google Chrome is based on Chromium, but they're not the same browser.</strike>

This is what you want: (since Chromium isn't officially supported)

```
DefaultSelenium selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*custom C:/path/to/chromium.exe" , "www.google.com");
selenium.start();
```

Edit 2018-08: Looks like the accepted answer changed to a copy of this one several years later, so my original comment is no longer correct.  I'm leaving it there, but struck out, because the votes are misleading if I straight remove it.

Comment: Can you now pls add some demo code on how to use it.

Comment: @SAndrew This is a configuration line in the documentation.  If you're having trouble with it, you should ask a new question.

Answer (score 9):

On Unix systems, you can do something like

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser /usr/bin/google-chrome
```

And then you can use "*googlechrome" as the launch parameter when creating your DefaultSelenium instance.

Comment: This does not work for me. I get:
raise WebDriverException("Can not connect to the ChromeDriver")

Comment: I resolved my issue: I had to download the ChromeDriver binary

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255929/running-webdriver-chrome-with-selenium

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/detail?name=chromedriver_linux64_2.3.zip&can=2&q=

Answer (score 5):

(Python)

You can use chromium-chromedriver instead of the vanilla chromedriver. It can be installed via apt-get like "sudo apt-get install chromium-chromedriver"

In my scripts I then configure the chromebrowser and driver to use the chromium exe and chromedriver exe like:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = Options()
options.BinaryLocation = "/usr/bin/chromium-browser"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/usr/bin/chromedriver",options=options)
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

Comment: where do you download chromium-chromedriver? @Dylan

Comment: I believe it was through apt-get @Pie

Answer (score 3):

It's probably too easy, and I'm going to figure out what I did that is horribly wrong, but...

```
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

    options.BinaryLocation = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Chromium\Application\chrome.exe");

    using (var chrome = new ChromeDriver(options))
```

appears to work...

Answer (score 1):

For me, just add:

`chrome_options.binary_location = "/usr/bin/chromium-browser"`

Sample code:

```python
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver

display = Display(visible=1, size=(1600, 902))
display.start()
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument("--profile-directory=Default")
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-plugins-discovery")
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
chrome_options.binary_location = "/usr/bin/chromium-browser"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.delete_all_cookies()
driver.set_window_size(800, 800)
driver.set_window_position(0, 0)
print("arguments done")
driver.get("http://google.com")
```

It works with `Version 104.0.5112.101 (Official Build) Built on Ubuntu, running on Ubuntu 18.04 (64-bit)`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is...

In a Linux you can install, to use without an [X Window](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) (example: in a webserver) too... It’s nice to some tests.

```
apt install chromium-shell
```

In code, you'll need a chromedriver. Look at this:

[chromedriver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started)

In this case I'll use Python code, to open a Chromium instance in a headless mode:

```
def startBot():
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('/opt/chromedriver85', options=chrome_options)
    #driver.set_window_size(1366, 728)
    #aguardar carregamento em segundos
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)

    print("Get URL...")
    driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

Obs.:

> A headless browser is a great tool for automated testing and server environments where you don't need a visible UI shell. ([source](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome))

That's it!

Comment: The question is about **chromium-browser** (not **chrome**).

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu, I managed to run Chromium by launching it from Selenium like a standard Chrome without any modifications by installing the `chromium-chromedriver` package.

###### TL;DR:

If you happen to run Ubuntu, which switched to that questionable Chromium snap, a fitting chromedriver is already included. The executable is on the the `PATH` already: `/snap/bin/chromium.chromedriver`.

And if you also happen to use a vanilla selenium which searches for `chromedriver` in the `PATH`, the supposedly transitional do-nothing-package `chromium-chromedriver` (dpkg) is actually providing that: an “executable” (shell-script) `/usr/bin/chromedriver` exec-ing the above mentioned snap version.

On this [Ubuntu 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_20.04_LTS_(Focal_Fossa)) (Focal Fossa) installation, I also happened to have this transitional `chromium-browser` package, which is probably not needed at all, but it also provides a (useless?) wrapper and made me try a matching `chromium-chromedriver` package version first. I have both on `1:85.0.4183.83-0ubuntu0.20.04.2` from focal-updates.

```
python3 -m venv venv
. venv/bin/activate
pip install selenium
python3
```

In the [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-eval-print_loop):

```
from selenium import webdriver
d = webdriver.Chrome()
```