# Running Selenium WebDriver Python bindings in Chrome

Tags: python, linux, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I ran into a problem while working with Selenium. For my project, I have to use Chrome. However, I can't connect to that browser after launching it with Selenium.

For some reason, Selenium can't find Chrome by itself. This is what happens when I try to launch Chrome without including a path:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./obp_pb_get_csv.py", line 73, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Chrome() # Get local session of chrome
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 46, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/service.py", line 58, in start
    and read up at http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver")
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'ChromeDriver executable needs to be available in the path.                 Please download from http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list                and read up at http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver'
```

To solve this problem, I then included the Chromium path in the code that launches Chrome. However, the interpreter fails to find a socket to connect to:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./obp_pb_get_csv.py", line 73, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/bin/chromium') # Get local session of chrome
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 46, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/service.py", line 64, in start
    raise WebDriverException("Can not connect to the ChromeDriver")
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'Can not connect to the ChromeDriver'
```

I also tried solving the problem by launching chrome with:

```
chromium --remote-shell-port=9222
```

However, this did not work either.

PS. Here's some information about my system:

```
www-client: chromium 15.0.874.121
dev-lang:   python 2.7.2-r3 Selenium 2.11.1
OS:         GNU/Linux Gentoo Kernel 3.1.0-gentoo-r1
```

Comment: I just wanted to let you know that "--remote-shell-port" is not a valid command line option. See: http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/
("--remote-debugging-port" would be the correct one. Please be aware that you need to close all chromium instances before using that option. I.e. creating a new window in an existing browser session does not work).

Answer (score 137):

You need to make sure the standalone ChromeDriver binary (which is different than the Chrome browser binary) is either in your path or available in the webdriver.chrome.driver environment variable.

see http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver for full information on how wire things up.

Edit:

Right, seems to be a bug in the Python bindings wrt reading the chromedriver binary from the path *or* the environment variable. Seems if chromedriver is not in your path you have to pass it in as an argument to the constructor.

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver

chromedriver = "/Users/adam/Downloads/chromedriver"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com")
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Sorry forget to mention that. I got this link.

Comment: Tried the Chromedriver instead of Firefox Webdriver.. almost 3 times performance gain ..

Comment: Also, just want to mention that the argument passed to the constructor is the path to _ChromeDriver binary_ and *not* the _directory containing the ChromeDriver binary_ (wasted the past half an hour figuring out what was going wrong).

Answer (score 115):

**For Linux**

1. Check you have installed latest version of chrome brwoser-> `chromium-browser -version`
2. If not, install latest version of chrome `sudo apt-get install chromium-browser`
3. get appropriate version of chrome driver from [here](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html)
4. Unzip the chromedriver.zip
5. Move the file to `/usr/bin` directory `sudo mv chromedriver /usr/bin`
6. Goto `/usr/bin` directory `cd /usr/bin`
7. Now, you would need to run something like `sudo chmod a+x chromedriver` to mark it executable.
8. finally you can execute the code.

   ```
   from selenium import webdriver

   driver = webdriver.Chrome()
   driver.get("http://www.google.com")
   print driver.page_source.encode('utf-8')
   driver.quit()
   ```

Comment: Very nice! One note: I was only able to get this to work with the 32-bit chromedriver although I am running 64-bit linux.

Comment: On Ubuntu (14.04) you can install chromium-chromdriver package (e.g. with apt-get) and add the path of the chromedriver file to the PATH shell variable PATH="${PATH}":/usr/lib/chromium-browser/ If you add this to your .bashrc, you won't need to set it each time you want to test with selenium.

Comment: actually this answer should have a lot more upvotes. basically this is the way to go for every driver like the geckodriver.

Comment: My chromium-browser version is mentioned as (Chromium 67.0.3396.99 Built on Ubuntu , running on Ubuntu 16.04) but the link only has versions as 2.0-2.9. Need some help.

Comment: Please remove the display.stop() @Vicky, that doesn't work and gives ab error. By the way, thanks. May God bless you.

Answer (score 94):

**Mac OS X only**

An easier way to get going (assuming you already have [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) installed, which you should, if not, go do that first and let Homebrew make your life better) is to just run the following command:

```
brew install chromedriver
```

That should put the chromedriver in your path and you should be all set.

Comment: It can't work on Mac. `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH.`

Comment: @wyx Your environment might not be setup right. Try running `brew doctor` and see if that finds anything.

Comment: This is one of those warm and fuzzy moments when you're just happy that you have a Mac. So easy.

Comment: HEART! I love brew

Answer (score 54):

## For Windows

Download ChromeDriver from [this direct link](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.9/chromedriver_win32.zip) ***or*** get the latest version from [this page](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads).

Paste the `chromedriver.exe` file in your `C:\Python27\Scripts` folder.

This should work now:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

Answer (score 23):

For Windows, please have the `chromedriver.exe` placed under `<Install Dir>/Python27/Scripts/`.

Comment: and where to put in ubuntu ? 
int `/usr/lib/` or somewhere else?

Comment: Having the file in `PATH` wasn't enough, putting it to `/Scripts/` where the `ride.py` is worked.

Comment: Please suggest me in Linux envi? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to run Selenium Python tests in Google Chrome. I'm considering Windows (Windows 10 in my case):

**Prerequisite:** Download the latest Chrome Driver from: *[Downloads - ChromeDriver - WebDriver for Chrome](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads)*

***Way 1:***

i) Extract the downloaded ZIP file in a directory/location of your choice 
ii) Set the executable path in your code as below:

```
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='D:\Selenium_RiponAlWasim\Drivers\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
```

***Way 2:***

i) Simply paste the *chromedriver.exe* under *<Install Dir>/Python/Scripts/* (In my case, the folder was: *C:\Python36\Scripts)* 
ii) Now write the simple code as below:

```
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

Comment: The download site has *"Please note that we have migrated to a new ChromeDriver site.
Current site will be deprecated soon."*

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu, you can just do this:

```
sudo apt install chromium-chromedriver
```

and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows' IDE:

If your path doesn't work, you can try to add the `chromedriver.exe` to your project, like in this project structure.

[image: chromedriver.exe]

Then you should load the `chromedriver.exe` in your main file. As for me, I loaded the `driver.exe` in `driver.py`.

```
def get_chrome_driver():
return webdriver.Chrome("..\\content\\engine\\chromedriver.exe",
                            chrome_options='--no-startup-window')
```

`..` means `driver.py's` upper directory

`.` means the directory where the `driver.py` is located

Answer (score 0):

Since **Selenium 4.6.0**, you don't need to manually install **Selenium Manager(webdriver-manager)** as shown below because it is already included in Selenium according to [the blog](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/selenium-4-6-0-released/)

```
pip install webdriver-manager
```

And, since **Selenium 4.11.0**, the code below is enough because [Selenium Manager](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/selenium_manager/) can automatically discover your browser version installed in your machine, then can automatically download the proper driver version for it according to [the blog](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2023/whats-new-in-selenium-manager-with-selenium-4.11.0/):

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

*[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29858752/error-message-chromedriver-executable-needs-to-be-available-in-the-path/77039576#77039576) explains it with how to test Django Admin with Chrome, [Selenium](https://Selenium), [pytest-django](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-django) and [Django](https://github.com/django/django).