# chrome driver is not working in windows

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to run my python selenium scripts in chrome browser on windows. I downloaded chrome driver and placed the exe file in "C:\Python27\Scripts" but still I'm getting error as

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\INNOVATE\Desktop\workspace\Sample\sample.py", line 3, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.44.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 59, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.44.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\chrome\service.py", line 66, in start
    "ChromeDriver executable needs to be available in the path. "
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: ChromeDriver executable needs to be available in the path. Please download from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html and read up at http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver
```

what should I do?

Comment: Have you read the error message? Especially the part that says *ChromeDriver executable needs to be available in the path* and provides URLs to download that module?

Comment: Check this link for setting up ChromeDriver in python: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/8259152/4193730](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8259152/4193730)

Answer (score 1):

try this package.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import chromedriver_autoinstaller

chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()

#maximize the chrome
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

you can defiantly remove chrome_options or add more arguments.

Please see the documentation, https://pypi.org/project/chromedriver-autoinstaller/

Comment: NameError: name 'Options' is not defined

Comment: Please check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65962319/14735963
This should resolve your issues.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have performed all the required steps to open *Chrome* using Selenium.

**Step1:** Download *Chrome Driver* 
Latest Release of *Chrome Driver* you can found is *ChromeDriver 2.13*.
Please use Link [Chrome Driver](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html) to get the latest one.

**Step2:** Save the *Chrome Driver* to your Project Location and give the path of that folder in your code.
       In my case i have saved the Chrome Driver in 'S' drive.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","S://Chrome Driver//chromedriver.exe");
```

Please check the path again where i believe is the problem in your code.