# How to address "Options is not defined error" in Python Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, chrome-options

I've recently have gotten a problem where, while using Selenium, wanted to use my default chrome browser profile, so it's signed in and everything, but when searched up on google, it gave me a code which is basicallty this:

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("[path to the profile]")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path=[path to the webdriver])
```

The error that I've been getting is:

```
NameError: name 'Options' is not defined
```

How can I fix this and maybe there's a better way to load a chrome profile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things. Possibly you haven't imported the required module for `Options`. So to use an instance of `Options` you have to include the following *`import`*:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
```

Moreover, `chrome_options` is deprecated and you have to use `options` instead. So your effective code block will be:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("[path to the profile]")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path=[path to the webdriver])
```

Comment: Ok, it worked, but my profile isn't loading, without errors and correct .add_argument, any common reasons why?

Comment: @martispy For loading [**Chrome Profile**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50635087/how-to-open-a-chrome-profile-through-user-data-dir-argument-of-selenium/50637211#50637211) check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49270109/how-to-open-a-chrome-profile-through-python/49280195#49280195) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56443546/how-to-use-existing-login-token-for-telegram-web-using-selenium-webdriver/56445102#56445102) discussion.

Answer (score 2):

You need to import `Options` into the namespace:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
```

Comment: Ok, it worked, but my profile isn't loading, without errors and correct .add_argument, any common reasons why?