# Using webdriver to run in Chrome with Python

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium

I have always used Firefox in webdriver. I want to try using Chrome. I have downloaded chromedriver and included it in the Path variable. However, this code returns an error:

`>>> webdriver.Chrome()`

`selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home`

I have also tried including the path:

`>>> webdriver.Chrome('C:\Python34\chromedriver_win32.zip')`

`OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application`

What is the problem here? I am sorry if I am doing something completely wrong or my problem seems hard to solve. Any help will be appreciated. I have also searched all over the internet, but I have not found anything yet.

Seriously, can't anybody solve this problem?

Comment: For the sake of simplicity, include the `chromedriver.exe` in the same folder as your script.

Comment: You have to extract the zip folder in order to obtain the necessary `chromedriver.exe`

Comment: @malik that seemed to work a little. Got a different error:

Comment: @ma `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver_win32' executable may have wrong permissions. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home`

Comment: Please post a screenshot of the folder contents.

Comment: @ma only a chromedriver.exe in it. I got the file from https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

Comment: Now put your script in there.

Comment: Why don't you give a try to Splinter : https://splinter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running webdriver chrome with Selenium](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255929/running-webdriver-chrome-with-selenium)

Comment: @ric I'll try it later.

Comment: @ric seem to get the same problems with Splinter.

Comment: I was just suggesting it instead of plain WebDriver since Splinter has a very clean API...

Comment: @ric Think I'll try it after I get this fixed.

Comment: Have you read comment from "TheRookierLearner" of the high voted answer suggested by JeffC above he mention about passing a path and not a folder...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that I had to unzip the folder and instead of typing the path to the folder as an argument, you had to supply the .exe file in the path as well. Maybe it was an intermittent thing, or something that only didn't work when I posted the question.