# When I try to use Selenium with python to open a Chrome browser, windows gives me a FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2]

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
```

Then in windows PowerShell I get:

```
PS C:\Users\userName\PycharmProjects\untitled> python .\s_Chrome.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.49.2-py3.5.egg\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 62,
in start
stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)
File "C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\subproce
ss.py", line 950, in __init__
restore_signals, start_new_session)
File "C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\subproce
ss.py", line 1220, in _execute_child
startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Do I need to add something to PATH?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running webdriver chrome with Selenium](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255929/running-webdriver-chrome-with-selenium)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the `chromedriver` executable in your `PATH`. Go [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home) to get more information and to download chromedriver for various platforms.

Comment: Thank you @MattDMo!  I realized this over the weekend on my personal linux machine over the weekend.  Could have saved myself time if I had checked my stackoverflow questions more often.