# how do you see the Chrome webdriver using selenium

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I followed setting up chrome requirements for selenium.webdriver.Chrome, and I used the following code [Running webdriver chrome with Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255929/running-webdriver-chrome-with-selenium):

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
print driver.page_source.encode('utf-8')
```

I was very surprised to see that the code works, but no browser pops up. I would think this is almost impossible to develop, as I can't see what I'm doing right/wrong. How do I use selenium to actually see a functional Chrome driver (python)? Thank you

ANSWER:

set visible to 1, install emulator:

```
sudo apt-get install xvfb xserver-xephyr

display = Display(visible=1, size=(800, 600))
```

Comment: `driver = webdriver.Chrome(path_here)` needs to include the path to the chromedriver executable

Comment: no dice  `In [21]: driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/bin/chromedriver')

In [22]: 
`

Comment: I checked system, it is 64 bit as I thought, and I took the 64 bit driver. It is recent, but not cutting edge (2.9) should be stable

Comment: Not sure if it makes a difference, but I have `.exe` at the end of my path...

Comment: I'm on ubuntu, we use executables with no extension in a bin folder

Answer (score 1):

In java we add these two lines for executing code in chrome

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chromedriver");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

not sure if there something similar for python as well!