# find_elements_by_partial_link_text won't locate the elements

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

In the website i visit there are 7 links of the following structure:

```
<tr>
 <td>
  <a href="some link i will need to visit" title="some title"> some text... Episode ....
  </a>
 </td>
 <td> some date </td>
</tr>
```

Now i use the following code to fetch the episodes and put them in a list

```
chromedriver = "C:/.../chromedriver.exe"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)

driver.get("link containing the content")

episodes = driver.find_elements_by_partial_link_text('Episode')

print "episodes found: ", len(episodes)
```

This always prints `episodes found: 0`. I've tried using a piece from the beginning of the hyperlink text, but it still doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

[The link is this](https://kissanime.to/Anime/Hunter-x-Hunter-2011-Dub)

Comment: Can we see the actual website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from what @nullpointer null-pointed out, notice the delay in the webpage load - *the elements you are looking for are not immediately available and you need to [wait for them to be present](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits)*:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://kissanime.to/Anime/Hunter-x-Hunter-2011-Dub")

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@title,'Episode')]")))

episodes = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@title,'Episode')]")
print(len(episodes))

driver.close()
```

Prints `8`.

Answer (score 1):

Looking upon the link provided the DOM is

```
<a href="/Anime/Hunter-x-Hunter-2011-Dub/Episode-007?id=126436" title="Watch anime Hunter x Hunter (2011) (Dub) Episode 007 online in high quality"> Hunter x Hunter (2011) (Dub) Episode 007</a>
```

In which case you can use the following as well :

```
episodes = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@title,'Episode')]")
```

***Edit***: In case you want to refer to correct usage of `chromedriver`. Do have a look at :

[Running webdriver chrome with Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255929/running-webdriver-chrome-with-selenium)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work either :/ Could it be the chromedriver's fault? Also could you tell me where i can study the syntax you used inside the paarentheses?

Comment: @Alan - https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev for the details on x path. In case of driver issue, you certainly should have got an exception.