# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webdriver_manager' error even after installing webdrivermanager

Tags: python, selenium, windows-10, sublimetext3, webdrivermanager-python

I've installed webdrivermanager on my [windows-10](/questions/tagged/windows-10) system

```
C:\Users\username>pip install webdrivermanager
Requirement already satisfied: webdrivermanager in c:\python\lib\site-packages (0.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: lxml in c:\python\lib\site-packages (from webdrivermanager) (4.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\python\lib\site-packages (from webdrivermanager) (2.20.1)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm in c:\python\lib\site-packages (from webdrivermanager) (4.46.1)
Requirement already satisfied: appdirs in c:\python\lib\site-packages (from webdrivermanager) (1.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: BeautifulSoup4 in c:\python\lib\site-packages (from webdrivermanager) (4.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\python\lib\site-packages (from requests->webdrivermanager) (2018.11.29)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in c:\python\lib\site-packages (from requests->webdrivermanager) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.8,>=2.5 in c:\python\lib\site-packages (from requests->webdrivermanager) (2.7)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.25,>=1.21.1 in c:\python\lib\site-packages (from requests->webdrivermanager) (1.23)
```

Still whenever I am trying to use webdrivermanager I'm facing an error.

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
  driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  C:\Users\username\Desktop\Debanjan\PyPrograms>webdriverManagerChrome.py
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\username\Desktop\Debanjan\PyPrograms\webdriverManagerChrome.py", line 2, in <module>
      from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webdriver_manager'
  ```

Can someone help me, if I'm missing something?

Incase it adds any value, I'm using [sublimetext3](/questions/tagged/sublimetext3)

Comment: `webdrivermanager` and `webdriver-manager` - are different libraries. Your code is from `webdriver-manager` library, which has two aliases: `webdriver_manager` & `webdriver-manager` and could be installed by any of them.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

### Update (thanks to [Vishal Kharde](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5774070/vishal-kharde))

The documentation now suggests:

```
pip install webdriver-manager
```

---

**Solution:**

Install it like that:

```
pip install webdriver_manager
```

instead of `pip install webdrivermanager`.

**Requirements:**

The newest version, according to the documentation supports python 3.6 or newer versions:

[image]

**Reference:**
https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/

Comment: If using `conda`, this worked `conda install webdriver-manager`

Answer (score 12):

First install webdriver manager using the following command in command prompt opened from the python file path.

```
pip install webdriver-manager.
```

Next open your pycharm tool and go to `settings -> project interpreter ->` and click on + icon and search for webdriver-manager and install that.

And run the below code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

Answer (score 8):

You can try this

`py -3 -m pip install webdriver_manager`

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
python3 -m pip install webdriver-manager
```

I'm on windows so I'll leave this incase it helps anyone.

Answer (score 2):

I found that this one worked for me so:

```py
pip3 install webdrivermanager
```

Not sure if it'll help anyone, but pip3 works better than normal pip as it installs correct dependencies

Comment: This is another library ;) with irrelevant to topic-starter's code.

Answer (score 2):

some times just restarting your code editor can be the ultimate solution
that is what worked for me after spending 2 hours on the web trying to find out why the webdriver_manager is not picked up by python

use this to install

```
pip install webdriver_manager
```

and then restart your VScode if that is what you are using as a code editor
I don't know why I have to but it worked the time waste.

Answer (score 2):

for newer selenium versions, install package "webdriver-manager" from pycharm IDE

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

It is an installation error.

It can be solved by:

**pip install webdriver_manager**

Answer (score 1):

If you are using chromium browser for execution then you can:

1. Install webdriver with following command:

```bash
pip install webdriver-manager
```

2. When importing in your python file you should use:

```py
from webdriver_manager.**core**.utils import ChromeType
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to Pycharm preference -> Python Interpreter click at + button to add new module and search for webdriver-manager and install it manually. This resolved my problem in mac.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use: from webdrivermanager import ChromeDriverManager

Instead of : from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

Comment: did you mean `webdriver_manager` ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use latest, updated pip command from pypi.com site, where we can find all latest version commands:

**pip install webdriver-manager**

latest webdriver version is 4.0.1 for selenium 4

from https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/

Comment: Another duplicate answer, with all the information previously mentioned.

Answer (score -2):

This works for me in all python version.

```
pip install webdriver-manager
```

Here's Lib, Check out:
https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/

Comment: Duplicate answer, with no new information.

Answer (score -2):

Use this in code:
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Make sure u have installed a correct python version.

I have noted that it works on python version 3.7 or lower version.