# Import "webdriver_manager.chrome" could not be resolved when using Selenium in VS Code

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, visual-studio-code, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to use Selenium to test a web app, and my tests are running smoothly using `webdriver-manager`. I already pip installed the webdriver_manager and selenium. I am using the chrome driver, so the first lines of my code are

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

As I already said, the code runs and my tests are carried out. However, since I am using VS Code, the line `webdriver_manager.chrome` is highlighted in yellow with the warning *Import "webdriver_manager.chrome" could not be resolved Pylance (reportMissingErrors)*.

Does anyone know how to remove this warning or how to fix it? Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce your problem on my computer. Can you try to upgrade or downgrade the `Pylance Extension`?

Answer (score 4):

Instal this and restart.

```
pip install webdriver_manager
```

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem. You should restart your VS Code, it worked for me.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30877860)

Answer (score 1):

At times *`pip3`* works better than normal *`pip`* as it installs correct dependencies.

I'd recomment to use *`pip3`* to install [webdriver_manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63421086/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-webdriver-manager-error-even-after-instal) as follows:

```
pip3 install webdriver_manager
```

Additionally, you may need to restart the *VS Code*

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue while coding on PyCharm. I reinstalled the package with `pip install webdriver_manager` and updated pip because it was outdated and got everything working now

Answer (score -1):

Replacing `webdriver_manager.chrome` with `driver = webdriver.Chrome('..\drivers\chromedriver')` should solve your issue.

If you have any more questions, I prefer if you ask me in here
https://discord.gg/fjNX5MuTVq