# Selenium ChromeDriver issue using Webdriver Manager for Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-manager

When running this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from webdrivermanager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().download_and_install())
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
```

This results in the following exception at the line where the chromedriver is installed:

> TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple

Note that I am aware that there already exist many threads about this topic but since the webdrivermanager seems to have been updated majorly the previous solutions do not work.

Also a quick side note: I installed webdrivermager via conda instead of pip. but that should  not be of concern.

EDIT: Entire stack trace:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\stefa\OneDrive -
> Johannes Kepler Universität
> Linz\Dokumente\GitHub\briefly\src\crawler\crawler.py", line 19, in
>
> driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().download_and_install())   File
> "C:\Users\stefa\anaconda3\envs\briefly\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py",
> line 73, in **init**
> self.service.start()   File "C:\Users\stefa\anaconda3\envs\briefly\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py",
> line 72, in start
> self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,   File "C:\Users\stefa\anaconda3\envs\briefly\lib\subprocess.py", line 951,
> in **init**
> self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,   File "C:\Users\stefa\anaconda3\envs\briefly\lib\subprocess.py", line
> 1360, in _execute_child
> args = list2cmdline(args)   File "C:\Users\stefa\anaconda3\envs\briefly\lib\subprocess.py", line 565,
> in list2cmdline
> for arg in map(os.fsdecode, seq):   File "C:\Users\stefa\anaconda3\envs\briefly\lib\os.py", line 822, in
> fsdecode
> filename = fspath(filename)  # Does type-checking of `filename`. TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two issues in your code block as follows:

- You need to import *ChromeDriverManager* from `webdriver_manager.chrome`
- As per [Webdriver Manager for Python](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/) `download_and_install()` isn't supported and you have to use `install()`

So your effective code block will be:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
```

On [windows-10](/questions/tagged/windows-10) system the console output will be:

```
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Python Programs>python webdriver-manager_ChromeDriverManager.py
[WDM] -

[WDM] - ====== WebDriver manager ======
[WDM] - Current google-chrome version is 95.0.4638
[WDM] - Get LATEST driver version for 95.0.4638
[WDM] - There is no [win32] chromedriver for browser 95.0.4638 in cache
[WDM] - Get LATEST driver version for 95.0.4638
[WDM] - Trying to download new driver from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/95.0.4638.54/chromedriver_win32.zip
[WDM] - Driver has been saved in cache [C:\Users\Admin\.wdm\drivers\chromedriver\win32\95.0.4638.54]

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:50921/devtools/browser/c26df2aa-67aa-4264-b1dc-34d6148b9174
```

> You can find a relevant detailed discussion in [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webdriver_manager' error even after installing webdrivermanager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63421086/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-webdriver-manager-error-even-after-instal)

Comment: Did you try this with conda or pip? Conda cannot install webdriver-manager but only webdrivermanager and this package only contains the download_an_install function instead of the usual install function

Comment: Check the linked [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63421086/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-webdriver-manager-error-even-after-instal). It shouldn't matter whether you install through pip/conda. But `pip install webdriver_manager` followed by `from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager`

Answer (score 3):

Here my solution:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
s = Service('chromedriver/chromedriver96.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Install Webdriver Manager for Python:
   pip install webdriver-manager
2. Import ChromeDriverManager:
   from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
3. Use webdriver:
   service = ChromeService(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
   driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)

Comment: where ChromeService come from anything in python must imported first

Answer (score 0):

Adding this in case others stumble onto this. This uses a combination of `selenium` version 4+'s `Service` class and sets the `executable_path` to `ChromeDriverManager().install()` and it worked for me. This beats having to constantly update via homebrew.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


        web_driver = webdriver.Chrome(
            service=Service(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install()),
            options=opts
        )
```

Console output

```
/Users/ekim/opt/anaconda3/envs/bots/bin/python -m src.app.__main__ 
2024-02-21 12:13:14,064 - INFO - Initializing ChromeDriver...
2024-02-21 12:13:14,064 - INFO - ====== WebDriver manager ======
2024-02-21 12:13:14,380 - INFO - Get LATEST chromedriver version for google-chrome
2024-02-21 12:13:14,384 - INFO - Get LATEST chromedriver version for google-chrome
2024-02-21 12:13:14,384 - INFO - There is no [mac64] chromedriver "122.0.6261.57" for browser google-chrome "122.0.6261.57" in cache
2024-02-21 12:13:14,395 - INFO - Get LATEST chromedriver version for google-chrome
2024-02-21 12:13:14,609 - INFO - WebDriver version 122.0.6261.57 selected
2024-02-21 12:13:14,610 - INFO - Modern chrome version https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome-for-testing-public/122.0.6261.57/mac-x64/chromedriver-mac-x64.zip
2024-02-21 12:13:14,610 - INFO - About to download new driver from https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome-for-testing-public/122.0.6261.57/mac-x64/chromedriver-mac-x64.zip
2024-02-21 12:13:14,836 - INFO - Driver downloading response is 200
2024-02-21 12:13:15,305 - INFO - Get LATEST chromedriver version for google-chrome
2024-02-21 12:13:15,430 - INFO - Driver has been saved in cache [/Users/ekim/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/mac64/122.0.6261.57]

Process finished with exit code 0
```