# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webdriver_manager' error using Webdriver Manager for Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-manager, webdrivermanager-python

I am creating a project to automatically open a page, I installed Selenium, but it says that there:

```
no such module as webdriver_manager
```

and the directory "C:\Users\Nina\chromedriver.exe" is not valid.

Here's my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import webdriver_manager as manager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

s=Service(manager.ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://cms.instructure.com/courses/500236/pages/week-14-november-22-23')
```

I've been working on this for 2 hours already, so can someone help me debug these errors?

Comment: Can you update the question with the error stack trace?

Answer (score 3):

This error message...

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webdriver_manager'
```

...implies that the *`webdriver_manager`* wasn't properly installed.

---

### Reasons

Possibly you installed *`webdrivermanager`* as:

```
pip install webdrivermanager
```

Or you have installed *`webdriver-manager`* as:

```
pip install webdriver-manager
```

Hence you see the error.

---

### Solution

Instead of those, you need to install ***`webdriver_manager`*** as:

```
pip3 install webdriver_manager
```

Update your code as:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

s=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://cms.instructure.com/courses/500236/pages/week-14-november-22-23')
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussion in:

- [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webdriver_manager' error even after installing webdrivermanager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63421086/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-webdriver-manager-error-even-after-instal)