# Selenium problem with the webdriver version installed through webdriver-manager while getting started

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-manager

I'm struggling with Selenium because the *official* **Getting Started code** in the **Driver Management Software** section returns me an error:

OFFICIAL CODE

```
# Use Webdriver Manager for Python: https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/webdriver_manager

# Import code:
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

# Use the `install()` method to set `executabe_path` in a new `Service` instance:
service = Service(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())

# Pass in the `Service` instance with the `service` keyword: 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
```

ERROR

```
Current google-chrome version is 96.0.4664
Get LATEST chromedriver version for 96.0.4664 google-chrome
Driver [C:\Users\my_name\.wdm\drivers\chromedriver\win32\96.0.4664.45\chromedriver.exe] found in cache
```

The problem is that ***I've already downloaded the latest chromedriver version available***, as you can see in the image below:

The chromedriver version downloaded
[image: The chromedriver version downloaded]

My **Chrome Version is 96.0.4664.110** and I didn't find that version in the download drivers list, so I just downloaded the latest 96.0.4664 version (which was the 96.0.4664.45 version), as the error suggested.

Comment: Where is the error? I don't see any error as such.

Comment: Yhea it's not an error, my mistake! Cheers for the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These log messages...

```
Current google-chrome version is 96.0.4664
Get LATEST chromedriver version for 96.0.4664 google-chrome
Driver [C:\Users\my_name\.wdm\drivers\chromedriver\win32\96.0.4664.45\chromedriver.exe] found in cache
```

...aren't any errors as such but operational *log* messages.

---

Irespective of having downloaded the latest [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909654/how-does-chrome-driver-interact-with-chrome-browser/59927747#59927747) version available or even not having it, [**webdriver-manager**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63421086/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-webdriver-manager-error-even-after-instal) will download the matching [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53727887/what-is-benefit-of-using-chromedriver-over-webdriver-if-we-are-using-only-chrome/53744026#53744026) as per the [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) version installed within your system.

Though the *Chrome Browser* team recently pushed a minor update and the current version being ***Version 96.0.4664.110***, but the latest [ChromeDriver v96.0.4664.45](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=96.0.4664.45/) have been tested and seems to work perfecto with *Chrome Browser Version 96.0.4664.110*. So you are safe and all set.