# This used to run up to opening listings_dropdown (python/selenium test)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

after changing to service object for the driver manager (frome exe path which was giving a deprecated msg) test keep closing

what should i do here exactly to have it running
or am i doing this the wrong way?

```
import os
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://christiesre.crm.gabriels.net/")
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
listings_dropdown = driver.find_element(by=By.LINK_TEXT, value = "Listings")
listings_dropdown.click()

my_listings = driver.find_element(by=By.LINK_TEXT, value = "My Listings")
my_listings.click()
```

i get this even tho i have the latest webdriver for chrome

```
[WDM] - ====== WebDriver manager ======
[WDM] - Current google-chrome version is 102.0.5005
[WDM] - Get LATEST chromedriver version for 102.0.5005 google-chrome
[WDM] - Driver [C:\Users\cehu\.wdm\drivers\chromedriver\win32\102.0.5005.61\chromedriver.exe] found in cache
```

Comment: Your question title, and description aren't clear, so could please elaborate more, also i will suggest you to look into this [https://stackoverflow.com/a/70525438/11863448]

Comment: it just exits with code 0 without me seeing it clicks on those elements @Akzy (how would i make it run through the elements ? and why does it exits without driver.quit())

really new at this so that's why my post might be confusing