# Could not get version for google-chrome with the command: powershell "$ErrorActionPreference='silentlycontinue' using WebDriver manager and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriver-manager

I'm trying to create a script using python that separate 2 kind of websites , the one with SPF included and the others with SPF , and classify them using python, so in the beginning it worked perfectly but these daysit gives me a message error that I don't find a clue about it

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import re
import requests
import json
from datetime import datetime
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
import colorama
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

colorama.init()
def checkCaptchaPresent(driver):
    captchaFound = True
    while captchaFound:
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_id("captcha-form")
            driver.set_window_position(0, 0)
        except:
            driver.set_window_position(20000, 0)
            captchaFound = False
            return 0

def requestSPF(url):
    response = requests.get("https://api.sparkpost.com/api/v1/messaging-tools/spf/query?domain={}".format(url)).json()

    for error in response['results']['errors']:
        if "does not have an SPF record" in error['message']:
            print(Fore.RED + "{} does not have an SPF record".format(url))
            return [url]
    
    print(Fore.GREEN + "{} have an SPF record".format(url))
    return []

chrome_options = Options()
PATH = "webdriver/chromedriver.exe"
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--window-size=1000,1000')
chrome_options.add_argument('log-level=3')
# chrome_options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=SFPInspector")

while True:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(),options=chrome_options)
    driver.set_window_position(20000, 0)
    search_term = input("Enter search term: ")
    number_results = int(input("Max number of url to scrape: "))
    language_code = "en"

    driver.get('https://www.google.com/search?q={}&num={}&hl={}'.format(search_term, number_results+1, language_code))
    print('https://www.google.com/search?q={}&num={}&hl={}'.format(search_term, number_results+1, language_code))
    checkCaptchaPresent(driver)
    urls = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='search']/div/div/div[@class='g']//div[@class='yuRUbf']/a")
    websiteLink = []
    for url in urls:
        scrappedURL = url.get_attribute('href')
        print(scrappedURL)
        websiteLink.append(scrappedURL)

    filteredURL = []
    for i, url in enumerate(websiteLink):
        match = re.compile("^http.*com[/]")
        matchedURL = match.findall(url)
        
        filteredURL += matchedURL

    filteredURL = [url.replace('https:', '').replace('http:', '').replace('/', '') for url in filteredURL]

    noSPFURL = []
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=int(10)) as pool:
        for res in pool.map(requestSPF, filteredURL):
            noSPFURL += res

    print(Style.RESET_ALL)
    driver.close()
    fileName = datetime.now().strftime("%d%m%Y-%H%M")
    print("Saving reports: report/{}_AllSite_{}.txt".format(''.join(e for e in search_term if e.isalnum()), fileName))
    with open('report/{}_AllSite_{}.txt'.format(''.join(e for e in search_term if e.isalnum()), fileName), 'w') as filehandle:
        for link in websiteLink:
            filehandle.write("{}\n".format(link))

    print("Saving reports: report/{}_NoSPF_{}.txt".format(''.join(e for e in search_term if e.isalnum()), fileName))
    with open('report/{}_NoSPF_{}.txt'.format(''.join(e for e in search_term if e.isalnum()), fileName), 'w') as filehandle:
        for link in noSPFURL:
            filehandle.write("{}\n".format(link))
```

The output message is as follows:

```
====== WebDriver manager ======
Could not get version for google-chrome with the command:  powershell "$ErrorActionPreference='silentlycontinue' ; (Get-Item -Path "$env:PROGRAMFILES\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe").VersionInfo.FileVersion ; if (-not $? -or $? -match $error) { (Get-Item -Path "$env:PROGRAMFILES(x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe").VersionInfo.FileVersion } if (-not $? -or $? -match $error) { (Get-Item -Path "$env:LOCALAPPDATA\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe").VersionInfo.FileVersion } if (-not $? -or $? -match $error) { reg query "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Google\Chrome\BLBeacon" /v version } if (-not $? -or $? -match $error) { reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Google Chrome" /v version }"
Current google-chrome version is UNKNOWN
Get LATEST chromedriver version for UNKNOWN google-chrome
Trying to download new driver from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/98.0.4758.102/chromedriver_win32.zip
Driver has been saved in cache [C:\Users\dell\.wdm\drivers\chromedriver\win32\98.0.4758.102]
Enter search term:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message...

```
====== WebDriver manager ======
Could not get version for google-chrome with the command:  powershell "$ErrorActionPreference='silentlycontinue' ; (Get-Item -Path "$env:PROGRAMFILES\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe").VersionInfo.FileVersion ; if (-not $? -or $? -match $error) { (Get-Item -Path "$env:PROGRAMFILES(x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe").VersionInfo.FileVersion } if (-not $? -or $? -match $error) { (Get-Item -Path "$env:LOCALAPPDATA\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe").VersionInfo.FileVersion } if (-not $? -or $? -match $error) { reg query "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Google\Chrome\BLBeacon" /v version } if (-not $? -or $? -match $error) { reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Google Chrome" /v version }"
Current google-chrome version is UNKNOWN
Get LATEST chromedriver version for UNKNOWN google-chrome
```

...implies that the [**Webdriver Manager**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63421086/7429447) was unable to retrieve the version of the installed [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) browser within the system through any of the below [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) commands and [registry](/questions/tagged/registry) query:

- *`Get-Item -Path "$env:PROGRAMFILES\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe").VersionInfo.FileVersion`*
- *`Get-Item -Path "$env:PROGRAMFILES(x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe").VersionInfo.FileVersion`*
- *`Get-Item -Path "$env:LOCALAPPDATA\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe").VersionInfo.FileVersion`*
- *`reg query "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Google\Chrome\BLBeacon" /v version`*
- *`reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Google Chrome" /v version`*

---

### Deep Dive

This issue was discussed in details in the following discussions:

- [google-chrome version is UNKNOWN with webdriver_manager 3.5.3 (Win)](https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/webdriver_manager/issues/307)
- [base64 encode powershell commands](https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/webdriver_manager/pull/310)

and was finally fixed through [fix powershell determination and str concatenation](https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/webdriver_manager/pull/328)

---

### Solution

Upgrade  [webdriver-manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63421086/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-webdriver-manager-error-even-after-instal) to the latest version of [webdriver-manager 3.5.4](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/)

Comment: is there any solution to that

Comment: @SaadOL Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Answer (score 0):

If your chrome is installed under `C:\Program Files (x86)` then read the following:

The issue for me was in the `powershell` invoked command :

> (Get-Item -Path "$env:PROGRAMFILES(x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe").VersionInfo.FileVersion

try to invoke it yourself and you'll find :

```
Get-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\Program Files(x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:2
+ (Get-Item -Path "$env:PROGRAMFILES(x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chr ...
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Program File...tion\chrome.exe:String) [Get-Item], ItemNotFoundExcep
   tion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemCommand
```

***The problem resides in an omitted space between `Program Files` and `(x86)`***
i.e it should be

- `C:\Program Files (x86)`

and not

- `C:\Program Files(x86)` (*no such folder under windows OS*)

The tricky part is that in the [source code file](https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/webdriver_manager/blob/1e7c551aae7a446be2783fc4af9a71bab34af7f6/webdriver_manager/utils.py#L167), the space actually **exists** between the environment variable `PROGRAMFILES` and `(x86)` :

```
        r'(Get-Item -Path "$env:PROGRAMFILES (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe").VersionInfo.FileVersion',
```

I think raw-stringifying (`r'`) that command wiped off ,somehow, the space.

---

***side note*** : It's noteworthy to mention that a possible fix is en route to be merged, which the pull requester mentioned in a comment [there](https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/webdriver_manager/pull/324#issuecomment-1054010544):

> As one can see, the reading the version from the registry is about
> 22.000 times faster that spawning powershell process to do the same thing. More importantly, the read chrome version will be correct (and
> not UNKNOWN)

A simple solution is to uninstall google chrome and reinstall it under one of the other stacktraced paths (e.g. `C:\Program Files`)