# Hide the WebDriverManager logs with GeckoDriver and Mozilla

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-manager

This is not a big probleme i am not stuck.

Do you know if it was possible to hide this message:

```
====== WebDriver manager ======
Current firefox version is 91.8
Get LATEST geckodriver version for 91.8 firefox
Driver [C:\X\X\.wdm\drivers\geckodriver\win64\v0.31.0\geckodriver.exe] found in cache
```

Because a made a loop and i have this message 10 times but a need to do a loop of 3500 iteration and i want, if it was possible, hiding this message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide the [webdrivermanager-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63421086/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-webdriver-manager-error-even-after-instal) logs you can initialize the env variable ***WDM_LOG_LEVEL*** with ***`0`*** value in your test as follows:

```
import os
os.environ['WDM_LOG_LEVEL'] = '0'
```