# Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable Requirement already satisfied error installing Webdriver Manager Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-manager, webdrivermanager-python

I'm attempting to import WebDriverManager for Chrome, but this is what I get

```
$ pip install webdriver-manager                                  
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable           
Requirement already satisfied: webdriver-manager in ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (3.8.1)                                                                               
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from webdriver-manager) (2.25.1)                                                                     
Requirement already satisfied: python-dotenv in ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from webdriver-manager) (0.20.0)
```

$ python3                                                        Python 3.10.4 (main, Jun 29 2022, 12:14:53) [GCC 11.2.0] on linux                       Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > from selenium import webdriver
> > > from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
> > > from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
> > >
> > > driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           Traceback (most recent call last):
> > > File "", line 1, in                                                      File "/home/jakob/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 69, in **init**                                                               super().**init**(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",                   File "/home/jakob/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 92, in **init**                                                             super().**init**(                                                                     File "/home/jakob/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 277, in **init**                                                              self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)                                     File "/home/jakob/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 370, in start_session                                                         response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)                              File "/home/jakob/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 435, in execute                                                               self.error_handler.check_response(response)                                           File "/home/jakob/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response                                                     raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)                                  selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist                                                                    Stacktrace:                                                                             #0 0x7f04a8c85b13                                                              #1 0x7f04a8a8c688                                                              #2 0x7f04a8ab3b92                                                              #3 0x7f04a8ab0035                                                              #4 0x7f04a8aac5aa                                                              #5 0x7f04a8ae764a                                                              #6 0x7f04a8ae17a3                                                              #7 0x7f04a8ab70ea                                                              #8 0x7f04a8ab8225                                                              #9 0x7f04a8ccd2dd                                                              #10 0x7f04a8cd12c7                                                             #11 0x7f04a8cb722e                                                             #12 0x7f04a8cd20a8                                                             #13 0x7f04a8cabbc0                                                             #14 0x7f04a8cee6c8                                                             #15 0x7f04a8cee848                                                             #16 0x7f04a8d08c0d                                                             #17 0x7f04a8064b43

I cannot get an instance of Chrome up and running where as I have google-chrome-stable (103.0.5060.114-1) installed.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly there are multiple versions of Python involved. So it would be much safer to invoke `pip` via the **`exec module`** approach, so you are aware about the desired Python executable version.

You can follow the below steps:

- (optional) Uninstall the previously installed ***python3*** and install a fresh version of ***python3***.
- Install *Selenium*

  ```
  pip3 install -U selenium
  ```
- Install Webdriver Manager for Python

  ```
  pip3 install webdriver-manager
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webdriver_manager' error even after installing webdrivermanager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63421086/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-webdriver-manager-error-even-after-instal)
- [DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated selenium python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64717302/deprecationwarning-executable-path-has-been-deprecated-selenium-python/70099102#comment123917077_70099102)

Comment: So I actually solved it by inputting the following:
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

Comment: In the question you mentioned that the error was in this line only `driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))`