# Selenium 4 and webdriver manager for firefox fails to run in Ubuntu

Tags: selenium, ubuntu, selenium-firefoxdriver, webdrivermanager-python

Apologies I am quite new to all this so trying to figure out if I am doing the right thing. I am running Ubuntu 22.04 and Selenium 4.8

I installed latest Geckodriver from Mozilla GitHub, converted it into executable and then moved it to `/usr/local/bin/`

I then downloaded webdriver manager and tried to run the following snippet for Firefox:

```py
# selenium 4 - updating geckodriver for firefox
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service as FirefoxService
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=FirefoxService(GeckoDriverManager().install()))
```

When I run that, it starts downloading: `[WDM] - Downloading: 19.0kB [00:00, 13.9MB/s]` and then it fails I get following error: `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status 127`

full error:

```
[WDM] - Downloading: 19.0kB [00:00, 13.9MB/s]                   
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gizmo/PycharmProject/PythonProjects/web/firefox_selenium.py", line 6, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=Service(GeckoDriverManager().install()))
  File "/home/gizmo/PycharmProject/PythonProjects/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 196, in __init__
    super().__init__(command_executor=executor, options=options, keep_alive=True)
  File "/home/gizmo/PycharmProject/PythonProjects/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 286, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/gizmo/PycharmProject/PythonProjects/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 378, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/home/gizmo/PycharmProject/PythonProjects/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 440, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/gizmo/PycharmProject/PythonProjects/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status 127
```

Where am I going wrong?

Goal: tried to get the webdriver manager to update my geckodriver for Firefox - ran it as a test to see if it is all setup correctly.

Answer (score 3):

### Pre-requisites

Ensure that:

- *Selenium* is upgraded to *v4.0.0* or above

  ```
  pip3 install -U selenium
  ```
- *Webdriver Manager for Python* is installed

  ```
  pip3 install webdriver-manager
  ```

> You can find a detailed discussion on installing *Webdriver Manager for Python* in [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webdriver_manager' error even after installing webdrivermanager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63421086/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-webdriver-manager-error-even-after-instal)

---

You don't have to cast to `FirefoxService` instance and can use the `Service` instance. You can use:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=Service(GeckoDriverManager().install()))
```

> Note: Ensure that your [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) is updated to the latest version.

Comment: Isn't that for Chrome? I am specifically using FireFox

Comment: Ahhh, you were too early ;)

Comment: Sorry:). Ok, tried the above, still getting same error. It starts downloading and then fails

Comment: So the error _selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status 127_ is no more reproducible and the new issue sounds to be a different issue all together. Feel free to raise a new question with all the relevant details.

Comment: what do you mean, its the same issue as before, it starts downloading then fails? I'll update original as that was always the case

Comment: it throws the status 127 error as per original error and with your code snippet.

Comment: Checkout the updated answer and let me know the ststus.

Comment: Ran the commands `Requirement already satisfied: selenium in ./venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages (4.8.0)` and same for webdriver-manager `Requirement already satisfied: webdriver-manager in ./venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages (3.8.5)`  it did 3 downloads [WDM] - Downloading: 19.0kB [00:00, 15.8MB/s]                   
[WDM] - Downloading: 19.0kB [00:00, 17.6MB/s]                   
[WDM] - Downloading: 100%|██████████| 2.85M/2.85M [00:00<00:00, 16.1MB/s] then 5 lines failed and same error: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status 127
`

Comment: does this simply mean the webdriver is up to date or it's still failing?

Comment: I can see _`Downloading: 100%`_. Do you have the latest Firefox binary?

Comment: sorry for such a basic question - how do I check if my firefox has latest binary? do you mean is it up to date?

Comment: @Gizmo Check if Mozilla browser is updated to the latest version.

Comment: Checked - `(venv) gizmo@vm:~/PycharmProject/PythonProjects$ firefox --version
Mozilla Firefox 109.0`