# How to address certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate error using Selenium and ChromeDriverManager

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-manager, webdrivermanager-python

Even with the ton of information about this, each solutions won't work for me, I'm trying to run a basic selenium script and I get this error. Is there any solutions for my case (note that i use 3.10 python and that I'm working on a corporate computer under windows OS which has Zscaler installed, if it is somehow usefull)
Here is my code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

def openChrome():

    options= Options()
    options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
    driverweb= webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options= options)
    driverweb.get('https://pypi.org/', verify=False)
    driverweb.set_window_size(1000,700)
    driverweb.set_window_position(0,0)

openChrome()
```

I tried to use the command (webdriver-manager update --ignore_ssl=true) but i think i use it the wrong way cause it is saying that webdreiver_manager isn't a command.

Here is the whole error i get :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\201046329\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\201046329\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 386, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\201046329\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 1042, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\201046329\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 414, in connect
    self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "C:\Users\201046329\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 449, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(
  File "C:\Users\201046329\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 493, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\Users\201046329\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ssl.py", line 512, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "C:\Users\201046329\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ssl.py", line 1070, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\201046329\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ssl.py", line 1341, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\201046329\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 489, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\201046329\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 787, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\Users\201046329\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 592, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /109.0.5414/chromedriver_win32.zip (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\201046329\Desktop\testwebbrowser.py", line 17, in <module>
    openChrome()
  File "C:\Users\201046329\Desktop\testwebbrowser.py", line 12, in openChrome
    driverweb= webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options= options)
  File "C:\Users\201046329\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\chrome.py", line 39, in install
    driver_path = self._get_driver_path(self.driver)
  File "C:\Users\201046329\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\core\manager.py", line 30, in _get_driver_path
    file = self._download_manager.download_file(driver.get_url())
  File "C:\Users\201046329\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\core\download_manager.py", line 28, in download_file
    response = self._http_client.get(url)
  File "C:\Users\201046329\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\core\http.py", line 32, in get
    resp = requests.get(url=url, verify=self._ssl_verify, stream=True, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\201046329\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 73, in get
    return request("get", url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\201046329\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\201046329\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 587, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\201046329\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 701, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\201046329\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 563, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /109.0.5414/chromedriver_win32.zip (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)')))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### get(url: str)

[**get(url: str)**](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.get) simply loads a web page in the current browser session and accepts only the url (string) as an argument. So if you try to pass the additional parameter *`verify=False`* that would result in an *TypeError* as:

```
TypeError: get() got an unexpected keyword argument 'verify'
```

`verify=False` is a valid parameter only for the [Python Requests](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_requests_get.asp) module. See details in [GET and POST requests using Python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/get-post-requests-using-python/).

---

### This usecase

As a prerequisite you have to install [webdriver-manager](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63421086/7429447) and removing the *`verify=False`* argument, your code executes perfectly on my [windows-10](/questions/tagged/windows-10) box.

- Code block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
  from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

  driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
  driver.get('https://pypi.org/')
  driver.set_window_size(1000,700)
  size = driver.get_window_size()
  print(size['height'], size['width'])
  driver.set_window_position(0,0)
  position = driver.get_window_position()
  print(position['x'], position['y'])
  ```
- Console output:

  ```
  ====== WebDriver manager ======
  Current google-chrome version is 109.0.5414
  Get LATEST chromedriver version for 109.0.5414 google-chrome
  Driver [C:\Users\user.name\.wdm\drivers\chromedriver\win32\109.0.5414.74\chromedriver.exe] found in cache
  700 1000
  0 0
  ```

Comment: First of all thank you for your time ! I put the 'verify' because I thought it could solve the problem, so i get the same error without it. I think it might be because of a self-signed certificate, but i don't know how to by pass this.

Comment: Chech this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63421086/7429447) and uninstall/reinstall `webdriver-manager` once

Comment: Indeed it works with my personnal laptop, but with my corporate laptop I still get the same error. As I said i really do believe that the problem comes from certificates that have been signed by my compagny, ofc correct me if Iose myself here. I'll edit my post since I realized there's only a third of the error code. Thank you again for the help and for your time !

Comment: (And ofc i tried to uninstall/reinstall it as you advised, but i didn't worked, i'm still getting the exact same error, i tried with selenium too, so do I do that for every package related to selenium/webdriver-manager ?)

Comment: _`the problem comes from certificates that have been signed by my company`_ seems the blockage.

Comment: Okay thank you ! If you have any advice on where could be the blockage I'm taking it x) since I never worked with those. I'll check what I can find meanwhile, something like a way to block the certificate's checking ! Thank you for your work !

Comment: Just for feedback, I found out how to bypass the SSL Certification with 'import os' and 'os.environ['WDM_SSL_VERIFY']= '0' ', but as I expected, the compagny software 'Zscaler' is blocking the connection since it doesn't have a SSL to verify, so bypassing it seems to not be an option.

Comment: @CorentinGauquier Thanks for sharing [`WDM_SSL_VERIFY`](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/). Honestly I should have suggested that in the first place :) possibly got distracted with `requests.get('https://pypi.org/', verify=False)`

Comment: No problem ! It was a pleasure to talk to you, and thank you for helping out new users !

Comment: Did you find a solution @CorentinGauquier? I have exactly the same issue: company laptop with ZScaler and Python script with Selenium throwing that error: SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED. Working with our Tech Lead to try and find a solution for our team.