# Use selenium with chromedriver on Mac

Tags: python, selenium

I want to use selenium with chromedriver on Mac,but I have some troubles on it.

1. I download the chromedriver from [ChromeDriver - WebDriver for Chrome](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home)
2. But I don't want to put it to PATH.So I do this.

[image]

```
import os

from selenium import webdriver

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
DRIVER_BIN = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "bin/chromedriver_for_mac")
print DRIVER_BIN
browser = webdriver.Chrome(DRIVER_BIN)
browser.get('http://www.baidu.com/')
```

But I can't get the result I want.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/wyx/project/python-scraping/se/test.py", line 15, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(DRIVER_BIN)
  File "/Users/wyx/project/python-scraping/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 62, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/Users/wyx/project/python-scraping/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 71, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver_for_mac' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

Exception AttributeError: "'Service' object has no attribute 'process'" in <bound method Service.__del__ of <selenium.webdriver.chrome.service.Service object at 0x107f96150>> ignored
```

3. Then I run `brew cask install chromedriver`.And I only run this 
   without the driver path.

   ```
   browser = webdriver.Chrome()
   browser.get('http://www.baidu.com/')
   ```

But it can't work either.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/wyx/project/python-scraping/se/test.py", line 16, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
  File "/Users/wyx/project/python-scraping/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 62, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/Users/wyx/project/python-scraping/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 71, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

Exception AttributeError: "'Service' object has no attribute 'process'" in <bound method Service.__del__ of <selenium.webdriver.chrome.service.Service object at 0x105c08150>> ignored

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Finally I try to put it to /usr/bin

```
➜  Downloads sudo cp chromedriver /usr/bin
Password:
cp: /usr/bin/chromedriver: Operation not permitted
```

and I try to use `export PATH=$PATH:/Users/wyx/project/python-scraping/se/bin/chromedriver_for_mac` in .zshrc . But

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH.

So how to solve it，I want to use it with the driver path not in the PATH so I can deploy my project easily.

Solution:

1. `brew cask install chromedriver`
2. `which chromedriver` get the driver path
3. And then use it like this `webdriver.Chrome("/usr/local/bin/chromedriver")`

> But I don't know why so complex to use selenium.

Comment: as of 2023, the brew install chromedriver --cask location is `/opt/homebrew/bin/chromedriver`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH.

[To launch chrome browser using `ChromeDriver`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255929/running-webdriver-chrome-with-selenium) you need to pass [executable chromedriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home) location with executable itself into `executable_path`.

You should try as below :-

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
DRIVER_BIN = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "bin/chromedriver_for_mac")

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = DRIVER_BIN)
browser.get('http://www.baidu.com/')
```

Or set `PATH` variable [using command with executable](http://codrspace.com/rails4sandeep/install-and-set-path-to-chromedriver-on-mac-or-linux/) as :-

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/wyx/project/python-scraping/se/bin/chromedriver_for_mac
```

Then try to Initialize `ChromeDriver` as :-

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('http://www.baidu.com/')
```

Comment: This two methods I have tried.It show me the same error what I have said above @Saurabh Gaur

Comment: I know you've tried but you haven't pass executable chromedriver itself with location that's why you're in trouble

Comment: To lunch ChromeDriver you need to pass executable directory with executable file also not only directory, make attention

Comment: @wyx And you have to pass executable chromedriver path into `executable_path` variable, see provided answer carefully..

Comment: chromedriver_for_mac is not a directory ,ok?My screenshots shows it clearly.

Comment: Oh, that's my mistake but you have to pass this into `executable_path` as `webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = DRIVER_BIN)`

Comment: Once move this executable to some other fresh empty dir location from current and then try

Comment: `webdriver.Chrome("/usr/local/bin/chromedriver")` only this can work. The driver is installed by brew. But why.

Comment: Actually you are modifying the name of chromedriver to chromedriver_for_mac that's why @wyx it couldn't find when you installed through brew, and this case you just Initialize as `webdriver.Chrome()` and it itself would find the chromedriver executable from bin folder but it should be named as `chromedriver`..:)

Answer (score 8):

For sake of simplicity:

Download the chrome webdriver from this [link](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.39/chromedriver_mac64.zip). 
Copy the 'chromedriver' in the folder of python script.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os

url = 'http://www.webscrapingfordatascience.com/complexjavascript/'

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
DRIVER_BIN = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "chromedriver")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = DRIVER_BIN)

driver.get(url)

input('Press ENTER to close the automated browser')

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 7):

For me worked like this without complicating things

1. Download **chromedriver** from official **[link](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)** (notice version of Chrome browser)
2. Unpack ***.zip** file and file **chromedriver** copy to location **usr/local/bin/**
3. Remove any path you put in file and just go with **driver = webdriver.Chrome()**
4. If probem still exist try to reopen PyCharm since sometimes need to be reopened in case to work

Comment: One step to mention at the end: if not done, allow chromedriver in the security & privacy menu on your mac

Answer (score 3):

For me, installing chromedriver through homebrew worked like a charm on MacOS 11.

```
brew install chromedriver && brew update
```

Comment: this worked for me too. Also, remember apple might block this app from starting remember to unblock it from security & privacy.

Comment: as of 2023, the command is `brew install chromedriver --cask` and location is `/opt/homebrew/bin/chromedriver`