# WebDriverException: Message: Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -9 MAC

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I keep getting the same error with selenium trying to control chrome.

This is my code and the error that I get. I already opened chromedriver and allowed it to be executed from the security in pref system.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome. options import Options
from selenium. webdriver. chrome. service import Service


s= Service('chromedriver')
chromeOptions = Options ()
driver = webdriver. Chrome (service=s, options=chromeOptions)
```

```
WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/marclamy/Desktop/code/instagram_bot_detection/1_data_collection.ipynb Cell 10 in <cell line: 8>()
      6 s= Service('chromedriver')
      7 chromeOptions = Options ()
----> 8 driver = webdriver. Chrome (service=s, options=chromeOptions)

File /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/main_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py:69, in WebDriver.__init__(self, executable_path, port, options, service_args, desired_capabilities, service_log_path, chrome_options, service, keep_alive)
     66 if not service:
     67     service = Service(executable_path, port, service_args, service_log_path)
---> 69 super().__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
     70                  port, options,
     71                  service_args, desired_capabilities,
     72                  service_log_path, service, keep_alive)

File /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/main_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py:89, in ChromiumDriver.__init__(self, browser_name, vendor_prefix, port, options, service_args, desired_capabilities, service_log_path, service, keep_alive)
     86     raise AttributeError('service cannot be None')
     88 self.service = service
---> 89 self.service.start()
     91 try:
     92     super().__init__(
     93         command_executor=ChromiumRemoteConnection(
     94             remote_server_addr=self.service.service_url,
     95             browser_name=browser_name, vendor_prefix=vendor_prefix,
     96             keep_alive=keep_alive, ignore_proxy=_ignore_proxy),
     97         options=options)

File /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/main_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py:98, in Service.start(self)
     96 count = 0
     97 while True:
---> 98     self.assert_process_still_running()
     99     if self.is_connectable():
    100         break

File /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/main_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py:110, in Service.assert_process_still_running(self)
    108 return_code = self.process.poll()
    109 if return_code:
--> 110     raise WebDriverException(
    111         'Service %s unexpectedly exited. Status code was: %s'
    112         % (self.path, return_code)
    113     )

WebDriverException: Message: Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -9
```

Comment: It seems like typo on line where chrome options are defined, there is an extra space. I am not sure if this solves the problem, but you should try it.

Comment: no this is just a space, it's allowed in python syntax

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use selenium with chromedriver on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39428042/use-selenium-with-chromedriver-on-mac)

Comment: executable_path is deprecated....

Comment: Did you also set the PATH variable?

Comment: Yes. also my error seems to be more linked to the driver itself

Answer (score 0):

We're using python's selenium's [webdriver-manager](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/) to manage our driver and had this same error from this line

`driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())`

To fix it, we opened a chrome window -> settings -> about chrome -> update chrome. Or `chrome://settings/help` on your browser.

After it finished building the new version of chrome, that same line no longer generates the error.

Of course, this only worked since Google had pushed a new version of chrome with a bugfix for whatever was causing that.