# Selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriver: Message: unknown error cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:9515 "from chrome not reachable"

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, path, selenium-chromedriver

Exactly what the title says. When ran, Chrome does in fact open, but does not continue on because unable to connect. Prints

```
opening chrome (mac)
opened chrome
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 378, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 440, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:9515
from chrome not reachable
Stacktrace:
```

When I run `chromedriver` in terminal it successfully starts and returns

```
Starting ChromeDriver 110.0.5481.77 () on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
```

Current version of Chrome is 110.0.5481.100

Code is as follows

```
def open_chrome(port=9515, on_mac=True):
    my_env = os.environ.copy()
    if on_mac:
        print('opening chrome (Mac)')
        subprocess.Popen(['open', '-a', "Google Chrome", "--args",
                          f'--remote-debugging-port={port}', 'http://www.example.com'])  # , env=venv)
    else:
        print('opening chrome (Linux)')
        subprocess.Popen(
            f'google-chrome --remote-debugging-port={port} --user-data-dir=data_dir'.split(), env=venv)
    print('opened chrome')

class Bot():
    def __init__(self, port_no=9515, headless=False, verbose=False):
        print('initialising bot')

        options = Options()
        if headless:
            options.add_arguments("--headless")
        else:
            open_chrome()
            # attatch to the same port that you're running chrome on
            options.add_experimental_option(
                f"debuggerAddress", f"127.0.0.1:{port_no}")
        # without this, the chrome webdriver can't start (SECURITY RISK)
        options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
        # options.add_arguement("--window-size=1920x1080")
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
        self.verbose = verbose
```

`echo $PATH` returns
`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

Most of the stuff I can find on similar problems suggest PATH issue but because running `chromedriver` is successful I don't think it's PATH problem?  But also not sure since I don't see it in `$PATH`...

Comment: Does it work if you use something like this answer instead? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39428042/use-selenium-with-chromedriver-on-mac

Comment: @Jortega yes, I ran that exact code and it opened chrome and went to baidu.com

Comment: Is there a reason you need chrome to use 127.0.0.1:9515? Or do you not care and just want the browser to open and work?

Comment: @Jortega, you had the right idea. i just removed all the port statements and it runs.  now just having a problem with the parent script to this script looping in the middle of the instead of running to the end, but thats an entirely different problem. thank you tho!