# How to use chrome extensions with Selenium Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to use one of chrome's extensions inside my python code, how could I do this?
Is it possible?

Comment: Try this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255929/running-webdriver-chrome-with-selenium

Answer (score 1):

I know the solution in Java, hope it will provide you a hint how it can be done in python.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
String browserExtension = "path/to/the/extension/name.crx";
options.addExtensions(new File(browserExtension));
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```