# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service error using ChromeDriver Chrome through Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

So I have made a program on one computer using selenium and that worked, Now using it in another computer I get this error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service chromedriver

Now this same issue was mention in:

[Selenium python: Can not connect to the Service %s" % self.path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35624689/selenium-python-can-not-connect-to-the-service-s-self-path/49787301)

[Selenium python: Can not connect to the Service %s" % self.path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35624689/selenium-python-can-not-connect-to-the-service-s-self-path?lq=1)

[Selenium and Python3 ChromeDriver raises Message: Can not connect to the Service chromedriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41047957/selenium-and-python3-chromedriver-raises-message-can-not-connect-to-the-service)

however the solutions mentioned didnt work.

I am using chrome version 79 and have installed chromedriver 79, I tested writing chromedriver in command line and that works which means path is configured right, I have made sure 127.0.0.1 localhost is also in etc/hosts

Below is my code which works on my computer (so i doubt its an issue with the code):

```
chrome_options = Options()   
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  
with webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options) as driver:
    driver.set_window_size(800, 460) # takes two arguments, width and height of the browser and it has to be called before using get()
    driver.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom='150%'")
    driver.get("file:\\"+url) # takes one argument, which is the url of the website you want to open
    driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').screenshot(output)  # avoids scrollbar
```

In the last question I also tried this modification:

```
chrome_options = Options()   
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  
with webdriver.Chrome("C:\\chromedriver.exe",chrome_options=chrome_options) as driver:
    driver.set_window_size(800, 460) # takes two arguments, width and height of the browser and it has to be called before using get()
    driver.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom='150%'")
    driver.get("file:\\"+url) # takes one argument, which is the url of the website you want to open
    driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').screenshot(output)  # avoids scrollbar
```

which would instead give me this almost identical error message:

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service C:\chromedriver.exe

I am unsure where the issue could lie.

I am using windows by the way.

**EDIT: Things I tried and didn't work:**

1- running everything as both admin and normal

2- re-installing chrome

3- using the beta-chroma 80 and webdriver 80

4- using normal chrome 79 and webdriver 79

5- Having both the script and the driver in the same directory (while using a 
correct path)

6- Having an external path and have it setup as needed

7- Using it in the PATH folder.

8- Adding "127.0.0.1 localhost" to etc/hosts

9- Running service test

I have ensured in every test that everything was in it's correct placement, I have ran a reboot before every new test, and they always give me the same error, which also happens to occur if I had an incorrect path as well, but once I ran the code for a service and it gave me a different error as I had my webdriver in C:/ which required admin privilages, however re-running the test again with the correct privilages gave back the same error

**Update** the issue isn't exclusive to the chrome driver. Even following setup instructions for either the Firefox or edge drivers end up on the same issues. It makes me suspect that the connection is facing some issue. I have tried running the test codes provided by Mozilla for the setup and it didn't work.

Unsure if that does help much or at all.

Comment: is your `chromedriver.exe` file stored at `C:\chromedriver.exe`?

Comment: Yes, it is stored in both C:\ as well as my PATH directory

Comment: Try starting the chrome service on your own and check if you are able to access it in browser using something like http://localhost:port . Example to start chrome service ` service = Service('/path/to/chromedriver')
service.start()
driver = webdriver.Remote(service.service_url) ` https://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started . If there is issues in  accessing the service url then it may be related to firewall

Comment: Let me test that soon.

Comment: try using `webdriver.ChromeOptions()` instead of `Options()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service chromedriver
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **Browsing Context** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

---

You need to take care of a couple of things:

- Ensure that you have downloaded the exact format of the *ChromeDriver* binary from the [download location](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=79.0.3945.36/) pertaining to your underlying OS among:

  - **chromedriver_linux64.zip**: For *Linux OS*
  - **chromedriver_mac64.zip**: For *Mac OSX*
  - **chromedriver_win32.zip**: For *Windows OS*
- Ensure that `/etc/hosts` file contains the following entry:

  ```
  127.0.0.1 localhost
  ```
- Ensure that *ChromeDriver* binary have executable permission for the **non-root**  user.
- Ensure that you have passed the proper absolute path of *ChromeDriver* binary through the argument `executable_path` as follows:

  ```
  with webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=chrome_options) as driver:
  ```
- So your effective code block will be:

  ```
  options = Options()   
  options.add_argument("--headless")
  options.add_argument('--no-sandbox') # Bypass OS security model
  options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')  # applicable to windows os only
  options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")  # overcome limited resource problems
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  with webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe', options=options) as driver:
      driver.set_window_size(800, 460) # takes two arguments, width and height of the browser and it has to be called before 
      driver.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom='150%'")
      driver.get("file:\\"+url) # takes one argument, which is the url of the website you want to open
      driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').screenshot(output)  # avoids scrollbar
  ```

---

### Mandatory Considerations

Finally, to avoid **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using ensure that:

- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v79.0.3945.36](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=79.0.3945.36/) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 79.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v79.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/79.0.3945.36/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test` as **non-root** user.

---

### References

You can find a couple of reference discussions in:

- [Python Selenium “Can not connect to the Service %s” % self.path in linux server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50753093/python-selenium-can-not-connect-to-the-service-s-self-path-in-linux-server/50753175#50753175)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service chromedriver.exe while opening chrome browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50727595/selenium-common-exceptions-webdriverexception-message-can-not-connect-to-the-s/50742641#50742641)
- [How to configure ChromeDriver to initiate Chrome browser in Headless mode through Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46920243/how-to-configure-chromedriver-to-initiate-chrome-browser-in-headless-mode-throug/49582462#49582462)

Comment: It is still not working, I have also tested the suggestion to run the service as a test and it gives me the same issue, Also unsure if it means much if at all but it takes a while for that error to appear. meanwhile the program appears stuck.

Comment: @ZaidAlShattle Did you try replacing the `chromedriver.exe` from `C:` to `C:\some_directory` and execute your test as **non-administrator** user adding the _argument_ I have mentioned in my answer?

Comment: @ZaidAlShattle Did you add the keyword `executable_path` to the value of the absolute path of the chromedriver binary `C:\some_directory`? Single forward slash i.e. (`\ `) preceeded by the raw switch i.e. `r`?

Comment: I have tried the second one, I haven't tried changing the directory from C:/. I will try that.

Comment: I have tried that while running not as admin to unfortunately no avail.

Comment: While I have unfortunately gave up as this issue seems to be unexplained and I can't solve it. I will mark this as the answer to thank you for the effort and with hopes that some of this information helps someone else, cheers!

Comment: Try opening your chrome browser. I ran into this problem while using Django some minutes ago, I fixed it by changing ports for my Django and actually opening the chrome browser. For some reasons I do not understand,it can't open the browser by itself without me doing it.