# Can I use Watir webdriver with Chromium?

Tags: google-chrome, watir, watir-webdriver, chromium, selenium-chromedriver

I have only managed to execute tests with Google Chrome (using the chromedriver).

Can anyone give an example how to start executing tests with Chromium?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your Chromium binary can be located or set it explicitly.

```rb
Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.path = '/usr/bin/chromium'
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
browser = Watir::Browser.new driver
```

Comment: Is it possible to use Chrome driver only using by watir-webdriver. in the above code example, it needs to use selenium-webdriver also.

Comment: slight tweek worked for me:
`Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.driver_path = '/usr/lib/chromium'`
I think the method may have changed from `path` to `driver_path`. And my binary was installed in `lib`.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be possible, you just have to provide path to Chromium. A few pages you should check:

- http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver
- http://watirwebdriver.com/chrome/
- [Use Selenium with Chromium Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731953/use-selenium-with-chromium-browser)