# Use Chromium Browser with webdriverjs and Selenium

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, chromium

It's not clear how to use Chromium with WebDriverJS and Selenium. The code to create a Chrome driver is:

```
driver = new webdriver.Builder().
    usingServer(server.address()).
    withCapabilities({'browserName':"chrome"}).
    build();
});
```

I have searched through 'Capabilities' and I couldn't find how to set a path for Chromium instead of Google Chrome. There is a similar post that explains how to do this in Java ([Use Selenium with Chromium Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731953/use-selenium-with-chromium-browser)).

So, how can I run the Chromium Browser with Selenium using WebDriverJS?

Answer (score 0):

Following the instructions in [this wiki page](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs), I can run chromium browser with selenium using WebDriverJS. You need to download a ChromeDriver and export Path to your system's environment.

Answer (score 0):

1. download chromeDriver from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html for your system.
2. Run Selenium with this:  java -jar [PATH]\selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="[PATH]\chromedriver.exe"