# How to run a Chromium Browser with Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver, chromium

Is it possible to run a Selenium test in Chromium Browser (not Google Chrome Browser)?

My [Google Drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Drive) location:

[image: Google Drive location]

My Chromium location:

[image: Chromium location]

FYI: I am using Java

My code (at the moment I am running FirefoxDriver (gecko):

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class MainClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\User\\IdeaProjects\\testselenium\\drivers\\geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.seleniumhq.org/");
   }
}
```

I thought that this code would help, but it was without success. It runs Google Chrome, not Chromium:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Chromium {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\User\\IdeaProjects\\testselenium\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.binary", "C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\chrome-win\\chrome-win\\chrome.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.seleniumhq.org/");
    }
}
```

What could be the problem? How can this question be resolved?

Comment: As per docs [here](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/01_introducing_selenium.jsp#supported-browsers-and-platforms), chromium is not supported.

Comment: @Kamal by the way recently I saw programmers run autotests on Chromium using JavaScript and Selenium. I can't remember where I saw it

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731953/use-selenium-with-chromium-browser

Answer (score 9):

*Chromium Browser* have different version as follows:

- *Chrome Canary*
- Chrome from *Dev Channel*
- Raw build of *Chromium for Windows x64*

Not sure which *Chromium Browser* version you are trying to use.

However to use *Chrome Canary* version you can use the *ChromeOptions* and `setBinary()` method to set the *absolute path* of the *Chrome Canary* binary and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

  public class A_Chrome_Canary {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
          ChromeOptions opt = new ChromeOptions();
          opt.setBinary("C:\\Users\\AtechM_03\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome SxS\\Application\\chrome.exe");
          WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(opt);
          driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
          System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
      }
  }
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Google
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: Chrome_Canary]

---

### Update

Not clear from your comments but you need to download the latest *Chromium* binary from either of the official repositories:

- [The Chromium Projects](https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/download-chromium)
- [chromium.appspot](https://download-chromium.appspot.com/)
- [Chrome Canary - Nightly build for developers](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/canary/)

Comment: yeap, everything is working fine for now. I am just edited your code and Chromium started to run

Answer (score 3):

With the help of [DebanjanB's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54568535), I developed the following code that can run on Chromium:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

public class A_Chrome_Canary {

    public static void main (String[] args){

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\User\\IdeaProjects\\testselenium\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe");

    ChromeOptions opt = new ChromeOptions();

    opt.setBinary("C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\chrome-win\\chrome-win\\chrome.exe");

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(opt);

    driver.get("https://www.google.com/");

    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());

    }
}
```