# Using Selenium Chromedriver: Google Chrome vs. Chromium Browser

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, chromium

I'm using Chromedriver in the following way:

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--window-size=1420,1080')
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
chrome_options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
chrome_options.binary_location='/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable'
chrome_driver_binary = "/usr/bin/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_binary, chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

In trying to clear some space in my ec2 instance, I'm noticing I also have the following:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 197M Mar  1 20:43 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser
```

Does Chromedriver need chromium-browser as some sort of dependency, or am I OK to delete chromium-browser?  It appears I only use google-chrome with Chromedriver, but again I'm not exactly sure if I need chromium-browser on the backend of things.

Answer (score 0):

`chromedriver` is just interface plumbing that controls `chromium-browser`, which does the real work.

Comment: So are you saying I can't delete chromium-browser, since chromedriver needs it?  I always thought my chromedriver was just using google-chrome.

Comment: Hmm, you should do an `ls -l /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable` to see if it is large, or if it just a shell script that calls `chromium-browser`.

Comment: Here's what I get when I run that command:  lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 32 Feb 26 18:09 /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable -> /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome

Comment: Here's the file size: -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 179M Feb 26 18:09 /opt/google/chrome/chrome

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/difference-between-chrome-and-chromium/#:%7E:text=same%20as%20Chromium%3F-,Chromium%20is%20an%20open%2Dsource%20and%20free%20web%20browser%20that,as%20well%20as%20Adobe%20Flash.):

> - Chromium is an open-source and free web browser that is managed by the Chromium Project.
> - Google Chrome is a proprietary browser developed and managed by Google.
>
> Unlike Chromium, Google Chrome offers built-in support for media
> codecs like MP3, H.264, and AAC, as well as Adobe Flash.

---

### Conclusion

If your tests are not dependent on [*Chromium*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54568535/7429447) browser you can safely delete it.

Comment: Unfortunately, when I uninstalled chromium-browser, it wiped chromedriver.  I have no idea why.

Comment: That's bizarre. I still believe you downloaded/installed them seperately.

Comment: FYI Chrome is not a proprietary browser. The full source code of Chrome is already there in the Chromium repo, it's just that Chrome specific codes are not compiled when compiling Chromium