# No code runs after defining webdriver in Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

Consider:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)

print("Hello, World!")
```

I am running Python 3.10 on Linux [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29).

I was trying to play around with Selenium. However, any code that I write after defining the webdriver does not work.

It seems that the interpreter gets stuck after defining the webdriver. It opens the webdriver, but it only shows "data:," and nothing else and won't respond to any code written after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chromium support is limited on Selenium in my experience.

Please look at [the replies to this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731953/use-selenium-with-chromium-browser) which do mention chromium-driver and how to get it.

```
 sudo apt-get install chromium-chromedriver
```

Should get you the Chromium driver, and they have some example code there that doesn't look too outdated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. I only had Chromium installed on my computer and I assumed that the Chromium drivers and the Chrome drivers are the same thing (I still can't find any reference to the Chromium drivers).